# Issue with iText when doing document.Close... Unbalanced Save Restore state operators

Tags: itext

We have an application which was working fine as a monolith.
Now we are in the process of splitting the application
In this process, I am getting an error stating something as shown here below...
This happens only at the place of d.close()

```
Document d = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 50, 50);
......
.....
finally{
            if(d.isOpen()) {
                d.close();
            }
            byteOutputStream.flush();
            byteOutputStream.close();
            pw.close();
            return byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
```

(As a monolith the whole application was working fine)
(iText2.1.7 jar is used)

```
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.UtilDelegateImpl.mapSystemException(UtilDelegateImpl.java:241)
at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:84)
at <<stub path>>.retrieve(_fileName1Remote_Stub.java:1)
at <<filePath>>.retrieve(fileName2.java:778)
at <<filePath>>.onCustomAction1(fileName3.java:403)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:266)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:83)
... 43 more
```

Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.sanityCheck(PdfContentByte.java:3171)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.toPdf(PdfContentByte.java:245)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormXObject.(PdfFormXObject.java:88)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate.getFormXObject(PdfTemplate.java:241)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(PdfWriter.java:1257)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1169)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:780)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:409)
    at <>.createPDF(<>.java:135)
    at <>.getPdfData(fileName1Bean.java:339)
    at <>.retrieve(fileName1Bean.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
    at <>.retrieveIntercept(<>.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
    at <>_c01dfd09.retrieve(EJSRemote0SL<>Bean_c01dfd09.java)
    at <>Bean_c01dfd09_Tie.retrieve(_<>Bean_c01dfd09_Tie.java:1)
    at <>.*invoke(*<>_c01dfd09_Tie.java)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

Comment: Something is wrong in your question. You say that you use the ancient iText version 2.1.7 (released 7 July 2009) so you would have `com.lowagie` in your code, yet your error message mentions `com.itextpdf`, which only existed in iText versions starting from 5.0.0. Perhaps you have more than one iText jar in your build path?

Comment: The exception explains that you wrote a bug in your code. Since you don't show your code, we can't tell you *precisely* what you're doing wrong. We can only tell you that you didn't use a `restoreState()` for every `saveState()` or that you used a `restoreState()` without a `saveState()`. We also know that you either don't know which version of iText you're using, or that you're lying about it.

Comment: Alternatively... Have you checked whether there actually occurs some exception in your `try` block?  They may prematurely cause you to enter the `finally` block with some save/restore issues.

Answer (score 0):

So here it is...
First of all, I apologize if there was ambiguity in my question.
As said, version 2.1.7 is also used (thanks to the point made by Amedee). There is a 5.x version which I found in the shared libraries of the server.
Since the directory structure is totally different between the two versions, both the jars are maintained for a specific reason.

Also, I am new to this whole application myself and trying to get an understanding with people around in this project. When people who developed it may not be here, I thought a post may give me some idea. So, you are also partly correct Mr.Lowagie - I am ignorant on iText and doing my learning as well - I do not have a reason to Lie! :-).

Mkl, there is no exception in the try block. What eventually turned out was that the image was not getting generated or getting garbled for some other reasons. And it is being investigated. I have given this activity to a person who understands the system better than I do.

Thanks to all your mails and support my dear friends!